# How do I get ImageResizer to load the source image?

Tags: react-native, image, png

I'm using **react-native-image-resizer** in my React Native app.

I've tried giving assetPath, pathURI, and image (see below) to ImageResizer, and always get the same message:

```
err on ImageResizer Unable to load source image from path
```

I've verified that uri64 does encode the file, so I know that the file path and URI are correct.

```
 let maxWidth = 24;
  let maxHeight = 24;
  let compressFormat = "PNG";
  let quality = 100; // only used for jpeg
  let rotation = 0;
  let outputPath = ".";
  let options = {};
  let keepMeta = false;

  const assetPath = "../../../../../assets/Knob-54px.png" 
  const pathURI = "file://" + assetPath

  const uri64 =  Base64.encodeURI(pathURI ); 
  const image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + uri64; 

  console.log("uri64 ", uri64);
  console.log("image ", image);
   

  ImageResizer.createResizedImage(pathURI or assetPath or image, maxWidth, maxHeight, 
    'PNG', quality, rotation, outputPath)
    //, keepMeta = false,
    //options = {mode: 'contain'})
  .then(response => {
    console.log("response.uri ", response.uri)
    console.log("response.path ", response.path)
    console.log("response.name ", response.name)
    console.log("response.size ", response.size)

    // response.uri is the URI of the new image that can now be displayed, uploaded...
    // response.path is the path of the new image
    // response.name is the name of the new image with the extension
    // response.size is the size of the new image
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("err on ImageResizer", err)
    // Oops, something went wrong. Check that the filename is correct and
    // inspect err to get more details.
  });
```

Here's the source code on GitHub for the ImageResizer:

https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer